# Beginner - How to print the external values of an array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

## I want to write a function that receives an array as a parameter and then prints the array's external values better using loops.

e.g. If A = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12]

Then the call printFrame(A) would display as in the code shows.

This is as far as I can get so that I obtain an array with only 0 in the middle, not sure if this way can lead me to the final purpose ---- printing the frame of the array##

```
% the text was not showing clear enough I want it to display like the following
1   2   3    4
5            8
9   10  11  12 


function F = printFrame(A)
mat = [];
[m,n]=size(A);
for i=1:n
e = A(1,i);
mat = [mat,e];   
end
for j=2:(m-1)
e = A(j,1);
mat = [mat,e];
   for k = 2:(n-1)
   A(j,k)=0;
   g = A(j,k);
   mat = [mat,g];
   end
e = A(j,end);
mat = [mat,e];
end
for i=1:n
h = A(end,i);
mat = [mat,h];
end

for l = 1:length(mat);
F = fprintf('%5d',mat(l));
 if rem(l,n) == 0
    fprintf('\n');
 end
end 
fprintf('\n\n')
end
```

Comment: you really need to define what is this "external value"....doesn't make sense to me (unless someone can explain).....

Comment: Sorry but I have added the format that I would like to have in my code, hope that will make more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should be robust enough. I'm sure there's a more clever solution but this seems to work

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12];
dims = size(A);

logicalmatrix = true(dims);
logicalmatrix(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = false;

A = A.'; % Transpose because MATLAB works column-wise
output = A(logicalmatrix);
```

EDIT, per your comment:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12];
dims = size(A);

A = arrayfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', 0).';
A(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = repmat({''}, dims - 2);

outstr = sprintf(strcat(repmat('%2s ', [1, dims(2)]), '\n'), A{:})
```

Returns:

```
outstr =

 1  2  3  4
 5        8
 9 10 11 12
```

As with my above answer, I'm sure there's a move clever solution. While more compact, I'm not sure if the `arrayfun` call is going to be any faster than a `for` loop. This should be fairly robust, the only thing that isn't robust is the the string output in the `sprintf` call (the `%2s` part) which I included to make sure the cells are uniformly padded, otherwise you'd get this:

```
outstr =

1 2 3 4
5   8
9 10 11 12
```

You'll have to change the value to the width of your largest number (with a negative sign if negative). I've been contemplating a couple robust solutions for this, but haven't quite settled on one that's elegant.

Comment: I am so sorry to cause all that confusion, I have added the format of the array that I would like to have into the first few rows of my code. I need it to be a matrix not vector. Like a frame of the array, but only display the outer values. Hope that will make more sense, please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create a mask and apply that as a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/). `A` needs to be transposed to get the order you want (rows first, then columns).

```
B = A.'; %'
mask = bsxfun(@or, [1 zeros(1,size(B,2)-2) 1], [1; zeros(size(B,1)-2,1); 1]);
result = B(mask).'; %'
disp(result)
```

Comment: I am so sorry to cause all that confusion, I have added the format of the array that I would like to have into the first few rows of my code, hope that will make more sense, please take a look. 
Besides, is that any easier function that a beginner can use to achieve this? Like for loops? Because this one looks a bit confused to me.
Thank you.

Comment: @Chaney It could be done with loops, but in Matlab you usually try to avoid loops. `bsxfun` is a little "advanced", yes, but it's a very interesting and flexible function, so I recommend [reading up on it](http://ubcmatlabguide.github.io/html/speedup.html#29)

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as I could make it. The resulting matrix contains strings instead of numeric values, but if you're just printing it out that should be okay.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12];
S = num2str(A);
S(2:end-1,2:end-1)=' ';
disp(S);
```

Output is:

```
1    2    3    4
5              8
9   10   11   12
```